# Select with UNION ALL to display tablename as an additional column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

For MSSQL or MySQL, here is a query that unites two results into one:

```
SELECT boy as person from table1
union all
SELECT girl as person from table2
```

How to modify the query above so that the result contains the second (added) column with the name of the table (so it contains `table1` or `table2` value).

Comment: `SELECT boy  as person, 'table1' as tbl from table1 union all SELECT girl  as person, 'table2' as tbl from table2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can give string lateral with table name as second column

```
SELECT boy as person, 'table1' as column2 from table1
union all
SELECT girl as person, 'table2' as column2 from table2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `Hard code` the `tablename` in Second Column

```
SELECT boy as person,'Table1' as Tablename from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT girl as person ,'Table2' as Tablename from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add them as literals:

```
SELECT boy as person, 'table1' as tablename from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT girl as person, 'table2' from table2
```